# How can we get a set of rows starting with a specific row?

Tags: sql, db2

we have a database with the following config:

```
VALUE_1 DATE | VALUE_2 INT | VALUE_3 CHAR(4) | VALUE_4 CHAR(4) ...
```

1. the key is made by these four values
2. All these values can be repeated but
3. ... Can't repeat the same row twice (only if one of the values is different)

**The problem is:**
In our first `SELECT` we get the first 10 rows, after that, we want to get the first 10 rows beginning by the last one, ordered by `VALUE_1 DATE | VALUE_2 INT | VALUE_3 CHAR(4) | VALUE_4 CHAR(4)`.

**How can we get a set of rows starting with a specific row?**

```
select -> ...
OUTPUT: v1, v2 ... v10

select -> where VALUE_1 > v10, VALUE_2 = (or >) value ...
OUTPUT: v11, v12 ... v20
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would explain what you want to do.

Comment: DDL would be nice

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
CREATE TABLE T (VALUE_1 DATE, VALUE_2 INT, VALUE_3 CHAR(4), VALUE_4 CHAR(4) )

INSERT INTO T VALUES
  ( '2020-01-01', 1, 'A', 'A' )
, ( '2020-01-01', 2, 'A', 'B' )
, ( '2020-01-01', 2, 'A', 'C' )
 ,( '2020-01-01', 3, 'A', 'B' )
```

assuming the last row you got was the 2nd one (and there are no NULLs), this will get the next

```
SELECT * FROM T
WHERE   (VALUE_1, VALUE_2, VALUE_3, VALUE_4 ) > ( '2020-01-01', 2, 'A', 'B' )
ORDER BY VALUE_1, VALUE_2, VALUE_3, VALUE_4
```

See Table 3. Here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000746.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by val1, val2, val3, val4) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by (case when seqnum <= 10 then seqnum else 11 end), -- first 10 rows first
         seqnum desc  -- the rest in reverse order
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use functions.

Comment: @ianpolitavares . . . Huh?  Your comment doesn't make sense.  These are built-in functions that DB2 supports.

Comment: You can't use built in functions?  Or you can't use UDFs?

Comment: where seqnum between 11 and 20 is next 10 rows

Answer (score 0):

Based on the guess/assumption that you mean you can't use window functions (?), you can probably combine `limit` with `offset`:

```
Select
<some columns>
from
<your table>
order by
al1, val2, val3, val4
limit <how many rows you want to return>
offset <how many rows you want to skip>
```

So if you wanted, say, rows 101 through 110, you would use

```
limit 10
offset 100
```

Don't have access to a DB2 system at this point, but that should work, or be close.